# How do I override or reset a Mac without an admin password?

Tags: macbook-pro, administrator

A while ago, my remote job had mass layoffs and let ex-employees keep our computers. IT claimed they reset the computers remotely, but it didn't seem to work. My issue is that since I don't have access to the admin account, I can't download or update apps.

I've been trying to figure out a way to override or factory reset my Mac, but it seems like everything requires I have the admin password. I've tried booting with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> but nothing happens. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: as you learned that is not possible

Comment: You can install apps locally

Comment: This is *exactly* what a thief would need to do in order to use a stolen Mac. Therefore, it *needs* to be impossible, ideally.